# Can I add suffix in urlMapping for HttpPost in RestResource

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, rest-service, httppost, restresource

I'm having an apex class like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/api/v1')
global without sharing class MyRestService {
 @HttpGet
 global static List<sObject> getDataById() {...}
 @HttpPost
 global static List<sObject> createData() {...}
}
```

While @HttpGet method still uses the urlMapping as above, I want to add more suffixes for urlMapping in @HttpPost method (For example: '/api/v1/createData'). How could I achieve this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a wildcard in order to allow the class to respond to all suffixes:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/api/v1/*')
```

You can then determine the resource by reading the value from RestContext:

```
String resourceUri = RestContext.request.requestUri;
```

And from there, you can determine what you want to do. For example:

```
switch on RestContext.request.requestUri.removeStart('/api/v1/') {
  when 'createData' {
    createData();
  }
  when 'deleteData' {
    deleteData();
  }
  when else {
    respondAsBadRequest();
  }
}
```

You could also do other things, like using an interface class for dynamic programming. Really, the sky's the limit depending on your skill level.